# Why does RDC eat my keystrokes?

Tags: windows-7, windows-ce, remote-desktop, handheld

I'm trying to use Microsoft's Remote Display Control (version 2.03, copyright 2000) to view my Windows CE device on the desktop (not only is it nice for my "regular" handheld device, because it makes the display easier to see, especially in zoom mode, but it is even more important for the other devices I have to test, whose screen is too dim for me to make out exactly what's on the screen (it's like the vision test from h311) - which is necessary for debugging, of course) but for some reason I am not able to enter key strokes on the device while it's connected to the desktop. I can enter them neither on the desktop/in RDC nor on the handheld device itself while connected via RDC.

This, of course, is untenable (no pun intended).

The .exe is created in XP Mode, copied to a "holding tank" in Windows Explorer on the Windows 7 machine, then copied from there to the handheld device.

Then I connect from the handheld device by selecting Start > Programs > cerdisp > selecting OK in the "Remote Display Control" dialog, then Connect, then OK (and I do connect), then run the app on the desktop in the "WindowsCE" window that RDC supplies. It allows me to select menu items, but the keyboard is broken/mute...???

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround? The desktop is a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: As soon as I'm able to bountify this, I will; if anybody provides an "arrest and conviction" before then, I will award a post-solution bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a "cold boot" of the handheld device caused it to come back to responsiveness, keyboard-wise. These devices are betimes more peckish than a put-upon puddle of Platypi.